# How do I create a numpy array from string?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fft

I have a file reader that reads *n* bytes from a file and returns a string of chars representing that (binary) data. I want to read up *n* bytes into a numpy array of numbers and run a FFT on it, but I'm having trouble creating an array from a string.  A couple lines of example would be awesome.

**Edit:**
I'm reading raw binary data, and so the string I get looks like `'\x01\x05\x03\xff'...`.  I want this to become `[1, 5, 3, 255]`.

Comment: Example of the data structure you're working with?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Python 2, you can do this directly with `numpy.fromstring`:

```
import numpy as np
s = '\x01\x05\x03\xff'
a = np.fromstring(s, dtype='uint8')
```

Once completing this, `a` is `array([ 1, 5, 3, 255])` and you can use the regular scipy/numpy FFT routines.

In Python 3, the switch to default Unicode strings means that you would read in the data as a bytestring and use the `frombuffer` command instead:

```
import numpy as np
s = b'\x01\x05\x03\xff'
a = np.frombuffer(s, dtype='uint8')
```

to get the same results.

Comment: Is there a way to make it read two bytes at a time instead of one?

Comment: That's neat - I didn't know about that method within numpy.  I just gave it a try and am getting `array([ 1,  5,  3, -1], dtype=int8)` back instead.  Any idea what might be causing this ?

Comment: To read two bytes at a time instead of one, you can change the dtype argument to something else like `int16`, `uint16` - once you get into multiple-byte strings, though, you may have to byteswap the output in order to get the byte ordering correctly.  Just replace `a = np.fromstring(...)` with `a = np.fromstring(...).byteswap()`.

Comment: @dtlussier - Are you specifying the `dtype` as an unsigned integer?  -1 is 0xFF if you're dealing with signed values.

Comment: yes, sorry I'd missed that part of your solution.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I get a deprecation warning with this method now: `DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead`

Comment: @Bill thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer for a Python3-safe version with bytestrings and `frombuffer`.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> '\x01\x05\x03\xff'
'\x01\x05\x03\xff'
>>> map(ord, '\x01\x05\x03\xff')
[1, 5, 3, 255]
>>> numpy.array(map(ord, '\x01\x05\x03\xff'))
array([  1,   5,   3, 255])
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you've got coming in it's tough, but if it were comma delimited integers you could do something like this:

```
myInts = map(int, myString.split(','))
```