# What is the most efficient way to subdivide a large list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that contains the `RGBA` color data for a `1024*1024` image, meaning `4,194,304` integers in that list. I need to split it down into `1024` sub-lists with each of those having `1024` sub-lists containing the 4 channels in order to be able to use it for what I need.

I have tried using for loops to append data to new lists, but that is a very slow process. I just need the list to be divided every 4 integers. What is the most efficient way of doing this? I have numpy if that can be used for this somehow.

I suppose I should mention that the list comes from unpacking a `struct` from a `.raw` image, so if there is a way to have the list split upon creation while unpacking that would also work.

Comment: How do you load the image?  and unpack it?

Comment: @hpaulj I use struct.unpack('='+len(bytes)+'B', bytes)

Comment: So it's a large tuple of bytes?

Comment: @hpaulj actually all of that is inside of a list(). Well now it's inside of a np.array()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760095/convert-binary-string-to-numpy-array talks about loading a binary string or file directly into an array (without the `struct` unpacking).  With `dtype='u1'` the array should contain 1 byte ints rather than the normal 4 byte ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you could use [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) to get what you're after. Say you have a list of 12 elements:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(12)
>>> x
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

We'll reshape it to give rows of four elements each:

```
>>> x.reshape(-1,4)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

You can give `reshape` more than two dimensions, too, so say `x` was `5x5` RGBA image in a 100-element 1-d array, you could do `y = x.reshape(5,5,4)`, so that `y[0][0]` gives the four channels of the (0,0) pixel, `y[0][1]` contains the four channels of the (0,1) pixel, and so on.

Comment: Do you happen to know how efficient this is on extremely large lists?

Comment: @CameronAtkinson If your data is a numpy array, it's borderline instantaneous, since no copying should need to be done. It just gives you a different view into your data.